# Assign unique id to consecutive rows within a grouping variable in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have the following data.frame:

```
a <- data.frame(group = "A", value = rnorm(mean = 1, sd = 2, n = 150))
b <- data.frame(group = "B", value = rnorm(mean = 1, sd = 2, n = 150))
c <- data.frame(group = "C", value = rnorm(mean = 1, sd = 2, n = 150))
df <- bind_rows(a, b, c)
```

I'd like to create a unique ID for every consecutive pair of rows within a grouping variable (`group`), like:

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(...)
```

So each "dyad" within a group should have a unique ID

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `gl`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
    group_by(group) %>% 
    mutate(id = as.integer(gl(n(), 2, n()))) %>%
    ungroup
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. What is `gl` doing? I can't seem to find documentation

Comment: @Parseltongue it generates a factor column, which we coerce to inteeger with `as.integer`

Comment: Wow, very clever.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the `rep` function:

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(id = rep(seq(n()), each = 2, length = n())) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `dplyr` option using `ceiling` + `row_number()`

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(id = ceiling(row_number() / 2)) %>%
  ungroup()
```